# Orange badge near to review

Tags: support

From today onwards i started to see an orange badge near to review and it is not there on every page. I do not understand from where i got this also.. By navigating back using browser back button i seemed to get to the page and im attaching the screenshot.

[image]

I might be missing something here, but my colleagues do not seem to get this orange badge which contains a number. What is that and what does that infer? Clicking on it seem to load the entire page once more.

Comment: Now its totally gone..

Comment: @ShadowWizard : got it..:).. its like treasure hunting.. SO keeps popping up new things..wonderful...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the number of pending edit reviews. It is displayed if there are suggested edits in the review queue. On Stack Overflow, it is only displayed if there are 5 or more suggested edits in the queue.

It is only displayed to people who can review suggested edits, that is, people with 2000 or more reputation points.

Comment: Does it have something to do with user rep? Cuz i never noticed it until a few min back and i have been using SO for sometime now..:)..

Comment: Just edited the answer to explain this. Also, congrats on having become a 2K user!

Comment: okay that is great..

Comment: And by this you won't be able to suggest edits on Meta now! (except tag wikis) :-)

Comment: Thank you @hims056! I will miss it :-D

Comment: @S.L.Barth quick, take screenshot! :-)